# How to link a standalone draft as a new reply to an existing thread

Tags: gmail

I have a thread going on in GMail, and someone asks me to send a debug email autogenerated via a menu option in their app.

That works fine, except that I'm reluctant to send that debug email right away as-is; I'd really like to **avoid splitting the thread**. What I want is to send this new email draft *as a reply* to the existing thread.

Otherwise, it's just too disruptive on the conversation context ("did you see I sent you that email you asked must be somewhere check spam folder" etc etc etc), and just doesn't feel right. Shouldn't have to be that way.

Any hints on how to do that?

---

*Edit:* No, manual re-creation of the draft by copy-pasting back and forth to a new reply really looks like a last-resort option to me. Too much potential to inadvertently corrupt or miss some part of the large debug report. Also, the original draft has attachments, which'll need manual labor to transfer as well.

Comment: @pnuts, yep, I think that's an option! Could you please replicate that recipe in an answer?

Comment: Well... yeah, except that saving to g-drive drops attachments. I'd handled that already, but let this question linger for a while just for the remaining theoretical interest.